# How to access the gridview control in a usercontrol from a javascript method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, user-controls, master-pages

I am trying access a user control from a javascript method and find the gridview in that control to check for the number to checkboxes checked on gridview. 
But when I try to get the gridviews ID from usercontrol in JS method it shows an error: this name does not exist in the current context. Below is the code I wrote:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test.Web.uc"
MasterPageFile="~/SiteMain.Master" EnableEventValidation="false" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/UC1.ascx" TagName="uctest" TagPrefix="uc" ID="gv_uc" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
function FindCheckBox()
{
   var checkBoxSelector = document.getElementById('<%=gv_uc.("gvgridname").ClientID%>');
}
</script>
```

gvgridname is the gridview on the usercontrol.

Comment: This `gv_uc.("gvgridname").ClientID` looks wrong and should be just `gv_uc.ClientID`

Comment: Put `FindCheckBox()` in the UserControl or send the `ClientID` as variable to `FindCheckBox()`. That way it will work for multiple controls on a single page.

Comment: @Andrei Even if I try to to write gv_uc it says the name is not existing in current context.

Comment: @VDWWD so the client id of the usercontrol should be sent as a parameter to the FindCheckbox.?

Comment: Yes, that would probably be easiest: `function FindCheckBox(ID) { var checkBoxSelector = document.getElementById(ID); }`

Comment: @VDWWD is there a way to pass this ID to uc file

Comment: Why? The uc file knows the ClientID of the GridView, the parent does not.

Comment: @VDWWD sorry not clear actually, not able to replicate the same...

Comment: I've added an answer to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

On the parent page you can have the JavaScript function that accepts the `ClientID` variable from the UserControl.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FindCheckBox(ID) {
        var checkBoxSelector = document.getElementById(ID);
    }
</script>
```

Then in the UserControl you can call the function with the correct ID.

```
<input type="button" onclick="FindCheckBox('<%= GridView1.ClientID %>')" value="ClickMePlease" />
```

Or in the code behind of the UserControl

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "sendGridID", "FindCheckBox('" + GridView1.ClientID + "')", true);
```

**UPDATE**

If you need the ID of a Control in the parent, you need to use FindControl in the UC.

```
GridView gv = Parent.FindControl("GridView1") as GridView;
Label1.Text = gv.ClientID;
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I need the id of the gridview on the parent page not on the usercontrol, i need to check if the checkboxes are checked or not in the gridview that is present in the usercontrol.

Comment: Updated my answer, with that you can find the ID of the GridView in the Parent.